# git: independent version control in sub directory?

Tags: git

I have a project which is under git version control. Everything works smoothly.

I also have "buildtool" directory which have some script for testing,deployment and setup.

Sometime while changing branch I want that directory to be latest and also I want it to be under version control ?

How do I achieve that ?

Comment: Why do it this way instead of using branches?

Comment: Have you looked at `git submodule`s this allows you to combine various repositories

Comment: buildtools have script which are independent of actual project content and even if the actual project is at different branch, buildtools have script which needed for running the project so they should be at latest or some choosen version. ( question can be asked another way : How do I merge only single subdirectory ? )

Comment: You could commit changes in the directory on a separate branch and merge the branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for submodules (cudos to Adrian Cornish for first suggesting it)  You've technically got two different projects that have loose coupling, but no real source code coupling.  Start off by putting them in separate repositories.  Then either leave them completely separate or use submodule to link the build content into the source content.